# Android Development: Koltin -> How do you use the id name you created in xml and call it in activity without creating a new varaiable

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following this tutorial video

In the activity.xml I created a toolbar with the id name

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_excerise_activity"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
```

Then in the mainActivity.kt in the on create method they just call the +id name without defining the variable. How is that done?

```
class ExceriseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_excerise)


    setSupportActionBar(**toolbar_exercise_activity**)
}
```

}

So some how they just called toolbar_excerise_activity id name without defiing the variable. How is that done

Comment: This is a capability provided by `kotlin-android-extensions`. It is a compiler plugin, but it’s deprecated now. You can do a web search to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using view binding for this.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityExceriseBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityExceriseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolBar)
}
```

view binding will create a binding class for all of your xml layouts.
The binding class name depends on the file name ex:
`my_layout.xml` will result in a `MyLayoutBinding` class being created.
Also in the xml anything with an id will then exist in the binding class.
The binding will have the camel case versions of the ids names in the xml.
meaning `@+id/my_id` will create a `myId` variable in the binding class